# How can I set the default build mode in a Visual Studio project generated by CMake?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I use CMake to generate a VS project.
The `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` is `RelWithDebInfo;Debug;MinSizeRel;Release`. (Whatever the order)
So the default build mode in VS is always `Debug`.
How can I change it by CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR, As far as I know, what you are asking for is currently not supported.

There's [`CMAKE_DEFAULT_BUILD_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_DEFAULT_BUILD_TYPE.html), but at the time of this writing, it only supports the Ninja Multi-Config generator (you'll get at error if you try to use it with a generated Visual Studio buildsystem). There's an issue ticket tracking a request for this variable to be supported for Visual Studio generators: [CMAKE_DEFAULT_BUILD_TYPE for Visual Studio #20820](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20820).

In the meantime, if you build by commandline, I think you have keep manually specifying [`--config`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-config) (unless you write an alias for your shell that specifies it implicitly).